# Is there a way to query.all() in peewee?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, peewee

I need to transfer all data from an SQL table to an html page. In SQLAlchemy I would do something like this:

```py
class Author(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first = db.Column(db.String(80))
    last = db.Column(db.String(80))


@app.route('/authors')
def get_authors():
    authors = Author.query.all()
    # Serialize the queryset
    result = authors_schema.dump(authors)
    return jsonify({'authors': result.data})
```

Is there a something like `authors = Author.query.all()` in peewee?

Comment: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.select

Answer (score 8):

To my knowledge, a direct equivalent does not exist in peewee, though there is an `all` method in the `Dataset` extension, documented [here](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html?highlight=all#reading-data). You can do this pretty easily using a list comprehension:

```py
authors = [author for author in Author.select()]
```

Or even just `authors = list(Author)`. However, if you're trying to return these as JSON, it won't work because your list of authors is populated by instances of `Author` and Flask's [`JSONEncoder`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.JSONEncoder) will not work with this type out of the box. You can get around this by using peewee's `dicts()` method:

```py
authors = [author for author in Author.select().dicts()]
```

The full example would look like this:

```py
@app.route('/authors')
def get_authors():
    authors = [author for author in Author.select().dicts()]
    return jsonify(authors)
```

Instead of serializing using `dicts` I often use [`marshmallow`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). For example you create an `author_schema` like so:

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class AuthorSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    first = fields.String()
    last = fields.String()

author_schema = AuthorSchema()
```

and use it like so (not showing imports):

```py
@app.route('/authors')
def get_authors():
    authors = author_schema(Author, many=True)
    return jsonify(authors)
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, would you please comment if there is anything wrong with the above? The code is tested and my answer is more complete than the others..

Comment: advanced use case warning: when you do `authors = list(Author)` the final instances inside the list are lazy-loaded, but somehow it was using the full instance memory on my machine (OOM) during a big query. imagine you have images for an author and it is inadvertently fetching all of those somewhere

Answer (score 4):

so i make this.

```
@app.route('/authors')
def get_authors():
    authors = Author.select()
    return render_template('aurhors.html', authors=authors)
```

And in html something like this.

```
 {% for a in authors %}
 <p>{{a.author_name}}</p>
 {% endfor %}
```

I only in begining of studying python, so thank for help.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is .dicts(), a method [well-hidden in the docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html?highlight=dicts()#retrieving-row-tuples-dictionaries-namedtuples), which returns an iterable peewee-specific type:

```
response = {'authors': []}
authors = Author.select()
for author in authors.dicts():
    response['authors'].append(author)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work of you're working with APIs:

```
return list(Account.select().dicts());
```